# Adding of new calculated column based on user input date

Tags: r, shiny

This is the snapshot of the data that I have

```
Date         price Industry  stock
29/10/2018   3      Airline   A
28/10/2018   4      Airline   A
27/10/2018   2      Airline   A
29/10/2018   5      Bank      B
29/10/2018   3      Food      C
28/10/2018   4      Bank      B
27/10/2018   2      Bank      B
27/10/2018   6      Food      C
```

I also have price , start and end date inputed by the user.

```
dateRangeInput('dateRange',
      label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
      start = min(dailyprice$Date), end = max(dailyprice$Date))
```

I have filtered the data set into a reactive function and plotted Date vs Price.
Now I need to to plot graph based on a new calculated column.
A new column should be added with **formula = price - price on start date(input$dateRange[1]) for that particular stock i.e. price on the date inputed by user**
If user has selected 27/10/2018 as start date then output should be

```
Date         price Industry  stock  NewCol
29/10/2018   3      Airline   A      1   (3-2)
28/10/2018   4      Airline   A      2    (4-2)
27/10/2018   2      Airline   A      0    (2-2)
29/10/2018   5      Bank      B      -1   (5-6)
29/10/2018   8      Food      C       2   (8-7)  
28/10/2018   7      Bank      B       1
27/10/2018   6      Bank      B       0
27/10/2018   6      Food      C       0
```

How can I perform this calculation?

I have tried these codes but did not get desired result:

```
  row <- subset(d , Date == input$dateRange[1] )
  d$newcol <- eval(parse(text="price - row"), d)
  sapply(d, function(d){d-row})
```

Comment: Look into `dplyr::mutate`, the `data.table` package, or just `d$newcol <- d$price - row['price']`. Using `eval(parse(` is almost always a really bad idea. There doesn't seem to be anything shiny specific here, so you should be able to use any option that adds a new variable to a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach -- not showing a graph, but hope this covers the gist of the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df <- readr::read_table("
Date         price Industry  stock
29/10/2018   3      Airline   A
28/10/2018   4      Airline   A
27/10/2018   2      Airline   A
29/10/2018   5      Bank      B
29/10/2018   8      Food      C
28/10/2018   7      Bank      B
27/10/2018   6      Bank      B
27/10/2018   6      Food      C
")

df$Date <- format(lubridate::dmy(df$Date), '%Y-%m-%d')

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(
    'dateRange',
    label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
    start = min(df$Date), 
    end = max(df$Date)
  ),
  tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df_new <- reactive({
    selected_date <- lubridate::ymd(input$dateRange[1])
    df %>%
      group_by(stock) %>%
      mutate(
        price_at_date = price[Date == selected_date],
        new_price = price - price_at_date
      )
  })
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    df_new()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Shiny App]